# deep copy a list of user defined class

Tags: c#, list, inheritance, copy

i have a list of class of below type

```
public class Class1
{
    public string str1 { get; set; }
    public string str2 { get; set; }
    public int int1 { get; set; }
    public double dbl1{get;set;}
    public List<Class2> cls2 { get; set; }
    public List<string> str3 { get; set; }

}
```

in which Class 2 is also a user defined class like:

```
public class Class2
{
    public string str4{ get; set; }
    public Class3 cls2 { get; set; }
}
```

which `Class3` is also another user defined class.
I need to copy a `List<Class1>` to another list of this type without any reference to the first list.

I used the below ways but they were unsuccessful.

1. `.CopyTo()` to an `Class1[]` array and then `.ToList()` but this hold the references
2. `.ToList()` but this hold the references
3. I used the ways of serializable and deserializable but the class could not be serializable.

Comment: You will just have to write a Method. Optionally implementing the IClonable interface.

Comment: Are you happy to write a `DeepClone()` method (or implement a Copy Constructor) for each class? (I'd avoid implementing  `ICloneable` because it doesn't specify whether it's deep or shallow - and [Microsoft recommend that it not be used](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icloneable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).)

Answer (score 0):

You should use write a generic method that uses serialization, that way you can easily achieve deep cloning to complex objects with good maintainability.

Refer to this:
[How do you do a deep copy of an object in .NET (C# specifically)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129389/how-do-you-do-a-deep-copy-an-object-in-net-c-specifically)

Comment: i use serializable but it does not work and cant serialize the list.

Comment: then add your code that does that, please, so we can have a look

Comment: ' public object DeepClone(object obj)
        {
            object objResult = null;
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                BinaryFormatter bf=new BinaryFormatter();
                bf.Serialize(ms,obj);
                ms.Position = 0;
                objResult = bf.Deserialize(ms);
            }
            return objResult;
        }'

Comment: Whats the error you get? Is your class decorated with [Serializable] attribute?

Comment: first i am very thank you for your time and help. error make in bf.Serialize(ms,obj).

Comment: no problem. I think it's because your class didn't have [Serializable] attribute on your class. If it was helpful, please mark the question as answered and feel free to upvote the answer ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I use serialization and deserialization method from NewtonSoft.Json package and it worked well.